# Rails 3: Get current view's path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, path, view, routes

I'm interested in creating a standard for my layouts where each view would be wrapped in a container named according to a specific convention.

Just for instance, if I had:

```
resources :foos
```

I would want the views to be wrapped in divs like so:

```
<div id="foos_view"> foos#index here </div>
<div id="foo_view"> foos#show here </div>
<div id="new_foo_view"> foos#new here </div>
<div id="edit_foo_view"> foos#edit here </div>
```

So, basically I'd like to use the route name, but substitute 'path' for 'view'.

My question is, is there some way to get the route name for the current view?

Ie. if my request is `example.com/foos/new` is there anything I can call in the view or controller that would return `new_foo_path`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to do this, as the path helpers simply do a call to `path_for()` and fill in the required params, so there's no method call to do it in reverse.

However, this is Ruby, so it's fairly easy to write a quick helper to return the string that you want. The current controller name can be accessed via `controller.controller_name` and the action name via `controller.action_name`.

Something like this should do you:

```
def html_id

   string = ""

   if controller.action_name =~ /new|edit/
      string += controller.action_name + "_"
   end

   if controller.action_name =~ /index|create/
     string += controller.controller_name
   else
     string += controller.controller_name.singularize
   end

   return string += "_view"

 end
```

Comment: Bingo. I wasn't aware of the `controller.controller_name` method, thanks :)